# Is there any way for me to view a webpage on my iphone in Safari offline?

Tags: iphone, safari

I need for the javascript and css to work (though naturally I understand anything that makes external requests will not work, this is fine). I am happy to download the html files and assorted assets if it helps though I suspect it will not.

'Reading List' does nothing for me. Safari is enabled to back up to my iCloud, I have safari set to automatically save offline. But every webpage (e.g. a wikipedia article) I have picked, if I add it to the reading list and then go offline, it tells me I can't view it.

Comment: Have you tried exporting web archives? Open the share sheet, go to "Send As", pick "Web Archive", then tap "Save to Files"

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much @Kevin Grabher this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Kevin Grabher for the answer.

For those who want to use this, to get to 'Send As' you should press 'options' after pressing the bottom middle button.

There are natural and understandable limitations, namely that you will need to make sure you arrange things such that you capture all the assets in doing this. There's several ways to do so. For me I just inlined the assets I needed, hosted locally on my computer, accessed my local server, did this webarchive thing and hey presto, it works!